# Change path in linux

Tags: linux, r

Although I thought I'm close to be professional in Linux but apparently I'm still a beginner. When I login to a server, I need to use the latest version of R (a statistical software). R is installed in 2 places. When I run the following command

```
which R
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/R
```

and then

```
R --version
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

apparently it is an old version and I know the last version of R is installed in

```
/usr/local/bin/R
```

I know I should change the path. Am I right? and How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the following in your `.bashrc` you will get the newer `R` first, because bash will search that directory before the other one.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

**Update**: Since the OP is apparently using `tcsh`, the correct way to set the path is to use `setenv` inside `~/.profile` or `~/.tcshrc`.

```
setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I do not have .bashrc . I only have .profile .

Comment: @vtt what is your shell?

Comment: @vtt try that line in .profile.  If that doesn't work try creating a .bashrc file

Comment: I did both and not successful.

Comment: -rw-------  1 dmgroup csgrad    33 Feb  4 21:25 .bashrc

Comment: PID TTY          TIME CMD
20585 pts/2    00:00:00 tcsh

Comment: Yes! It is working. I just added to .login . Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to have multiple versions of interpreters/compilers co-existing in different paths (I have 3 different versions of `python` in my `/usr/local/bin`). Just create an alias in your `.bashrc` file in your home directory:

```
alias R="/usr/local/bin/R"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I do not have .bashrc . I only have .profile.

Comment: Did you try adding the alias to `.profile`? It's probably loaded when you first start up a shell. Otherwise, if you are using bash you can create a new `.bashrc` file with the command `touch .bashrc`. If you are using another shell like `ksh` you can add the alias in `.ksh` in the home directory.

Comment: I tried to add alias to .profile but it did not solve the problem. Here is the .profile: PATH=/usr/local/mpich/bin:/usr/local/pbs/bin:/usr/local/intel/bin:/usr/local/maui/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb
alias R="/usr/local/bin/R"

Comment: I also created .basrc and added alias to it. Still does not work.

Comment: Try adding the alias to a line of its own. Don't put it in with the path line. Also, what shell are you using? Run the command `ps -p $$` to print your current shell.

Comment: Actually I added alias on its own line.

Comment: PID TTY          TIME CMD
20585 pts/2    00:00:00 tcsh

Comment: Looks like you are using `tcsh`. In that case, you'll need to create a file in your home directory called `.tcshrc`, add the alias line, then close all of your shells and then open them again.