# How to update to specific R version on Linux (Red Hat/CentOS), keeping the previous version?

Tags: r, linux, shiny, centos7

Perhaps a more accurate title would be: "How to switch from in-place (EPEL) R to side-by-side (version-specific) R installation on Linux (Red Hat/CentOS)?

A (possibly typical) upgrading R on Linux story...

**History:**

At some point in the past, I updated the version of R on our RHEL/CentOS 7 server using the default version pulled down by the `yum` package manager at that time. For example, `sudo yum install R` to version 3.5.2 at some point in early 2019. By default, this installs R at `/usr/lib64/R` for all users and completely replaces the 3.4.x version that had previously been installed there. Shiny Server was already installed, configured to run as user `shiny`, and it picked up the new version of R without a hitch.

**Situation:**

A year later, it is now time to bite the bullet and update the version of R that is running on the Linux server. Running `yum check-upgrade R` I find that the version available is 3.6.0. I actually want to install 3.6.3 AND I don't want to break all of my apps that are running on 3.5.2, so I need to use a different method.  Following the instructions found at https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/, I download the 3.6.3 .rpm file and install it. By default, this installs R at `/opt/R/3.6.3/`, leaving the 3.5.2 version as is. However, as soon as I complete the [Create a symlink to R](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/#create-a-symlink-to-r) step, none of my shiny apps work:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R  
sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

This should not be surprising.  My shiny apps all rely upon several R packages that have not yet been installed for this new version of R.  I can quickly get my apps working again on the previous version (3.5.2) by removing these symlinks until after I've installed the necessary packages in the new version:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/R  
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

Error messages in my shiny app log files (at `/var/log/shiny-server/<app name>-<user>-<datetime>.log`) confirm that the apps had failed to launch due to missing packages. To update the R packages in the shared library folder, I need to run the new version of R as sudo: `sudo -i /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/R` and install the necessary packages, e.g.,  `install.packages(c("shiny","devtools","rmarkdown","shinydashboard","tidyverse"))` in R.

Now that the R packages are installed, I can re-create the symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R  
sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

I verify that my apps are working with the new version of R.

Now I have some questions:

**Question 1:** After completing these steps, `R --version` still returns the old version (3.5.2).  But when I logged back in the following day, it opens 3.6.3.  Why?  Do I need to run a terminal command to get `R --version` to return the new version immediately or is opening a new terminal window the only way to achieve this?

**Question 2:** Running `sudo R --version` always returns the old version (3.5.2).  Running `sudo which R` returns `/bin/R`. Running `more /bin/R` reveals contents which state that it is "Shell wrapper for R executable." and has the "/usr/lib64/R" path hard-coded. I don't think I need this wrapper at this point. What is the recommended way to get these sudo commands to point to the new version?

I can make a backup copy of this file in my home directory (e.g., `cp /bin/R ~/binR.backup`) just in case, and then:

- Delete /bin/R?
- Replace /bin/R with a symlink to the new version (e.g., `sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/R /bin/R`)?
- Re-install the 'old' version into `/opt/R/3.5.2/` using a .rpm the same way I installed 3.6.3, install packages there, and then remove the `/usr/lib64/R` version (e.g., `sudo yum remove R`)?

---

Links to similar questions that I looked at but didn't answer my questions:

1. [How to upgrade R in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214061/how-to-upgrade-r-in-linux)
2. [Change path in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333183/change-path-in-linux)
3. [How can I load a specific version of R in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897335/how-can-i-load-a-specific-version-of-r-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:** I'm not sure why, but having multiple versions of R on your PATH can lead to unexpected situations like this. `/usr/local/bin` is usually ahead of `/usr/bin` in the PATH, so I would've expected R 3.6.3 to be found. Perhaps it has to do with Question 2.

**Question 2:** Some distros (like CentOS/RHEL) don't put `/usr/local/bin` on the PATH by default when using sudo. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/why-are-path-variables-different-when-running-via-sudo-and-su for details. The answers there describe several ways to add `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH when using sudo -- for example, modifying `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers` to include `/usr/local/bin` like:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

With R 3.6.3 ahead of the default system R in the PATH, you shouldn't have to delete `/bin/R` or `/usr/bin/R`. But eventually, I'd recommend installing multiple side-by-side versions of R the same way, using https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/, so it's easier to manage. The next time you install a new R version, you can just replace the symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`. The default system R (from EPEL) is meant to be the only R on a system, with in-place upgrades.

If you want to replace the default R 3.5.2 with a side-by-side R 3.5.2 (or 3.5.3), you could install R 3.5 from https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/, install all necessary packages, and have Shiny Server use the new R 3.5. Then uninstall the R from EPEL (`R-core` or `R-core-devel`) to fully switch over. From there, you could even create symlinks to R in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`, and not worry about adding `/usr/local/bin` to the sudo PATH.

Comment: Aha! `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` for my user, but as sudo it is not there. That does seem to address Question 1 and I'll investigate this more. This is clarifying: "The default system R (from EPEL) is meant to be the only R on a system, with in-place upgrades." I hadn't been thinking of the two types of installs as 'side-by-side' and 'stand-alone'/'in-place' but that classification makes a lot of sense. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Closing the loop: after removing the EPEL version (`sudo yum remove R`, and R-core, R-core-devel, R-devel, R-java, R-java-devel), `sudo which R` didn't find R anywhere anymore (since /usr/bin/R was removed). Creating a symlink `sudo ln -s /opt/R/3.6.3/bin/R /usr/bin/R` resolves this, as you say.